# Pip3 doesn't work because of SSL module error

Tags: python, macos, pip, openssl

Running into a weird situation where `pip install` works fine but `pip3 install` fails with the message below. Everything was working properly until recently I used virtual environment for the first time.

```
$ pip3 install yahoo_fin

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Requirement already satisfied: yahoo_fin in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.8.2)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I've come across several similar posts and I think I've tried them all including `brew install openssl`, `brew reinstall python`, `pip3 install certifi`...yet none of them works.

For your reference:

$ which python3:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

$ which pip3

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

$ python3 --version

```
Python 3.7.4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've hit a wall.

***Additional info since original post***

When I ran the following:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```

it returned:

```
LibreSSL 2.2.7
```

But then, when I ran this:

```
python3 -c "import ssl; print (ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Is the error above the crux of the issue? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: how did you install that version of python?

Comment: @GradyPlayer before the error occurred, I was using the one pre-installed on my mac. I re-installed using brew but getting the same error

Comment: I would maybe try pyenv to install and virtual env to manage the active version...

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was happening with me when I try to install packages with conda. The solution was to add the following paths to my system variable:

- C:..\anaconda3
- C:..\anaconda3\Scripts
- C:..\anaconda3\Library\bin

I presume there might be equivalents to these with pip/your python interpreter.

Side note: this also works for non-admin users, since in certain cases people switch to conda as it allows installing Python without admin rights.